# aws_cdk events rule target for cdk pipelines fails

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

below error pops when I try to target a CDK pipeline using events targets.

```
jsii.errors.JavaScriptError: 
  Error: Resolution error: Supplied properties not correct for "CfnRuleProps"
    targets: element 0: supplied properties not correct for "TargetProperty"
      arn: required but missing.
```

code is below

```
from aws_cdk import (
    core,
    aws_codecommit as codecommit,
    aws_codepipeline as codepipeline,
    aws_events as events,
    aws_events_targets as targets
)
from aws_cdk import pipelines

from aws_cdk.pipelines import CodePipeline, CodePipelineSource, ShellStep

class BootStrappingStack(core.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs

        repo = codecommit.Repository(
            self, 'Repository',
            repository_name='Repository'
        )

        source_artifact = codepipeline.Artifact()

        cloud_assembly_artifact = codepipeline.Artifact()

        pipeline = CodePipeline(self, 'Pipeline',
            synth=ShellStep("Synth",
            input=CodePipelineSource.code_commit(
                repository=repo,
                branch='master'),
            commands=[
                'pip install -r requirements', 
                'npm install -g aws-cdk', 
                'cdk synth']
            )
            )

        rule = events.Rule(self, 'TriggerPipeline',
            schedule=events.Schedule.expression('rate(1 hour)')
        )

        rule.add_target(targets.CodePipeline(pipeline))
```

The documentation for aws_cdk.events_targets works with codepipeline construct, however doesn't work as documented for `cdk pipelines`.

This needs to be addressed in the documentation, once I get to know what's the fix. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Otavio, you need to use the `codepipeline.IPipeline`.

You can use the `pipeline` property from CDK `CodePipeline` construct but in order to use that first you need to construct the pipeline using `build_pipeline()` method:

```
       pipeline = CodePipeline(self, 'Pipeline',
            synth=ShellStep("Synth",
            input=CodePipelineSource.code_commit(
                repository=repo,
                branch='master'),
            commands=[
                'pip install -r requirements', 
                'npm install -g aws-cdk', 
                'cdk synth']
            )
            )

        # You need to construct the pipeline before passing it as a target in rule
        pipeline.build_pipeline() 

        rule = events.Rule(self, 'TriggerPipeline',
            schedule=events.Schedule.expression('rate(1 hour)')
        )

        # Using the pipeline property from CDK Codepipeline
        rule.add_target(targets.CodePipeline(pipeline.pipeline))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
const pipeline = new CodePipeline(self, 'Pipeline' ....
```

Then:

```
rule.addTarget(new targets.CodePipeline(pipeline))
```

Comment: This works for the codepipeline construct, however doesn't work for CDK Pipelines construct.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `targets.CodePipeline` receives a `codepipeline.IPipeline` as a parameter. But what you are using instead is a `pipelines.CodePipeline`, which is a different thing. `CodePipeline` is more abstract construct, built on top of the `codepipeline` module.